# Performing native backups of an RDS SQL Server DB instance using the SQL Server Management Studio Backup UI

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssms, amazon-rds, sql-server-2017

I would like to perform backup and restore of AWS RDS SQL using the Backup UI provided by SQL Server Management Studio (under [DB]-> Tasks ->Backup).

Is there a way to do this?

[This article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/) describes the process using the `exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database` statement in query window. But I want to be able use the Backup/Restore UI provided by SQL Server Management Studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could not use SSMS UI to perform backup/restore operation. Reason for this is that you need to enter physical location for your backup file either local drive or network share in task wizard. Since AWS RDS does not allow you to access neither OS nor any drive, option for backup/restore from UI could not be used.

The way to achieve this is to create backup file in Amazon S3 bucket using exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database. More details at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Backup

and then to restore it using msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore.

By default AWS RDS does not allow native backup/restore support. You need to add option SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE to your option group for RDS instance.
Details at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.BackupRestore.html

If you want to restore backup from AWS RDS to any other SQL server on premise, you download the backup file from S3 bucket and  restore it in usual way